# Execute shortcode in backend

Tags: shortcode

So I have a plugin that creates some images like a gallery. I add it to the page with shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('foo', 'foo_add_gallery');
```

I would like to create an option so that the gallery can be previewed in the wordpress admin area. I have managed to make it work like so:

1.

Normally I add my gallery scripts and styles to the frontend with

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_enqueue_scripts');
```

Now I need to add them to the backend as well if I want to view the gallery, so I need to run

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_admin_enqueue_scripts');
```

(This is where scripts and styles for plugin admin are already added, and I need to add my frontend script and styles in here as well)

2.

I run ajax when I want to preview the gallery and in there I call the same function shortcode would call:

```
var postData = [
        {name: 'action', value: 'foo_show_gallery_backend'},
        {name: 'gallery_id', value: gallery_id}
    ];

    $.ajax({
        url: foo_data.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',   
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log( response)

        $('#some-div').html(response)

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });  


add_action('wp_ajax_foo_show_gallery_backend', 'foo_show_gallery_backend');

function foo_show_gallery_backend(){

   $data = foo_add_gallery($atts);

   echo json_encode($data);

   wp_die();

}
```

(My foo_add_gallery function creates some html and javascript and adds this to the page)

Then I add this response to the page in admin area in a div.

Comment: Where is this code running? Have you considered building a block instead?

Comment: The code is running in plugin admin where all plugin settings are. What would be the benefit of block?

Comment: Ah I see, I notice your PHP passes an `$atts` variable to `foo_add_gallery` but the variable comes out of thin air, is this a complete code example? Also can you clarify your question a bit further? This is a Q&A site so the question needs to be answerable in a factual manner, but a yes/no wouldn't work as an answer, and what if there is no correct answer? There are definitely improvements that could be made, but those wouldn't be because you did it wrong per say, I don't know how this could be canonically and concretely answered, it sounds more like a discussion

Comment: $atts was removed because its not relevant. I pass this parameter myself. I am interested wheater this getting of shortcode and json_encode it would cause it to fail in certain cases? I am not sure how else would I set this shortcode output in a backend div?

Comment: I still can't find a specific question I can answer in a concrete, factual manner. Perhaps instead you should ask how to render a shortcode in the Admin area, rather than if what you're doing is correct. For that, I would need to know where in the admin area you're doing this, is this a metabox? A block? TinyMCE preview? A custom hook That info is missing from your question, yet it's super important information needed to understand your question, please edit your question so that it's clear. Focus on your original problem instead.

Comment: I have a plugin section with options and inside I want to render shortcode in a div, nothing special here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a plugin section, can you rephrase/use different words? I can think of several things that could be called a plugin section that are very different